# Check count of user in a table for particular date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have table for which I want to check the **count** for particular user for dates between `01/04/2016 - 17/05/2016`

I have added the query like below

```
select count(CUser_Id) from inward_doc_tracking_trl
where CSTATUS_flag = 4
and NStatus_Flag = 1
and CUser_Id = 1260
```

now how to add the `date`  part and check ??

I am using `SQL server 2005`

Comment: ...and datecolumn between startdate and enddate...

Comment: @jarlh: is this fine `and U_datetime = '01/04/2016' and '17/05/2016'`

Comment: Use `between` operand, i.e. `and U_datetime between  '01/04/2016' and '17/05/2016'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BETWEEN` to filter between two dates :

```
select count(CUser_Id) from inward_doc_tracking_trl
where CSTATUS_flag = 4
  and NStatus_Flag = 1
  and CUser_Id = 1260
  and YourDateCol between '01/04/2016' and '17/05/2016'
```

**EDIT:** If I understood you, you need a group by clause :

```
select CUser_Id,count(CUser_Id) from inward_doc_tracking_trl
where CSTATUS_flag = 4
  and NStatus_Flag = 1
  and YourDateCol between '01/04/2016' and '17/05/2016'
GROUP BY CUser_Id
```

Comment: is this fine `and U_datetime between 01/04/2016 and getdate()`

Comment: Yes, but why don't you try instead of asking?:) @NK

Comment: hi, related to this I need one more thing. Can I ask here or should I ask new question ?

Comment: Depends on the size of the question :) If its something small, ask here. If not, open a new question.

Comment: Sure, I want the Count of all the documents of all the users from the table whose `CSTATUS_flag = 4` and  `NStatus_Flag = 1` and lie between the date I mentioned.

Comment: @NK Updated the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112173/discussion-between-n-k-and-sagi).

Answer (score 2):

Just add the date column to the conditions list:

```
select count(CUser_Id) from inward_doc_tracking_trl
where CSTATUS_flag = 4
and NStatus_Flag = 1
and CUser_Id = 1260
and U_datetime >= '2016-04-01' 
and U_datetime <= '2016-05-17'
```

Note I've used a different string format to represent dates then the one you used in your question. 
The reason for this is that `yyyy-MM-dd` is an ISO standard and thus sql server will always treat it the same, whereas the format `dd/mm/yyyy` is ambiguous:
does `01/04/2016`  stands for April 1st or January 4th of 2016?

Another thing: I always prefer using `>=` and `<=` instead of `between...and` - since `between...and` includes the first value but excludes the last, that's a little bit confusing. with `<=`, `>=` it's clearer.

Comment: @NK Yeah, I figured it out since I'm human and can look at the other date and find out, but sql server can't...

Comment: @NK  I  second Zohar on dates format. Casting of  '01/04/2016' as Date   is collation dependent and may hit you if application runs under other collation environment. Use ISO format or cast it explicitly and specify collation.

Answer (score 0):

Add date column of your table in the condition list.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CUser_Id) 
FROM 
    inward_doc_tracking_trl
WHERE 
    CSTATUS_flag = 4
    AND NStatus_Flag = 1
    AND CUser_Id = 1260
    AND YourDateColumn BETWEEN '2016-04-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2016-05-17 23:59:59.999'
```